# Alamofire not encoding / in httpBody

Tags: swift, encoding, alamofire

I'm trying to make a request to an API to recieve a token. What I've found is that Alamofire does not seem to encode the `/` part of my secret but still encodes all the other non-ASCII characters correctly... For example:

Secret: `hzgdKnJKyYGFyKqkh2/+JSnZO11sdyNhxnJUU8GR9uQ=`

Correctly encoded: `hzgdKnJKyYGFyKqkh2%2F%2BJSnZO11sdyNhxnJUU8GR9uQ%3D`

Alamofire encoding: `hzgdKnJKyYGFyKqkh2/%2BJSnZO11sdyNhxnJUU8GR9uQ%3D`

Notice how the `/` remains in the Alamofire encoding...

This is the full request code:

```
let params : Parameters = [
    "client_id" : "d92b3377-2226-46e9-8e39-8fa1246b1ba8",
    "client_secret" : "hzgdKnJKyYGFyKqkh2/+JSnZO11sdyNhxnJUU8GR9uQ=",
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
    "scope" : "transportapi:all"
]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseSwiftyJSON {
    response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

My question is obviously - is there a way to encode the `/` as part of Alamofire? I know I can encode it separately but then I can't use Alamofire's `.httpBody` because it then encodes all the encoded characters again... Quite a mess.